# Can we upload the profile photo for user object using code

Tags: apex

We Have one custom object called Employee and we are creating user from this employee record, and  we have option to upload profile photo field in employee object and I tried to upload the same profile pic for user record whenever the user record is created or updated with the Employee record with the profile photo field.

1. I am used "FullProfileUrl" Field from user object to upload Photo But it is showing error as **"Field is Not Writeable"**.

Answer (score 1):

There's an API that sits around the profile photo functionality - specifcally you want to call `setPhoto` on the `UserProfiles` class:

> `public static ConnectApi.Photo setPhoto(String communityId, String userId, ConnectApi.BinaryInput fileUpload)`

Of course, this means you need the binary data, not just a URL for the photo. You could download it with an HTTP request and use the body of the response as the binary data for this method.